# How could collateral effects be managed in Java8 streams

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I understand that Streams in Java8 can only be collected once (as in a `forEach()` termination) but I'm wondering if we could manage to "tap" into a stream in the middle of a chain of filtering and mapping tasks to produce some collateral effect.

In essence, "tapping" would be like doing a `forEach()` but returning the Stream at that point of the pipeline.

I'd use it like this:

```
List<User> createAndPersistRandomUsers(int count) {
  return IntStream.range(0, count)
    .boxed() // returns Stream<Integer>
    .map(UserBuilder::random) // returns Stream<User>
    .tap(userRepo::persist) // Collateral persist of user, returns Stream<User>
    .collect(toList()); // returns List<User>
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of to achieve what you want is [peek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) :

> Stream peek(Consumer action)
>
> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream,
>   additionally performing the provided action on each element as
>   elements are consumed from the resulting stream.
>
> This is an intermediate operation.

It allows you to perform an action on an element of the Stream while the Stream in being consumed.

```
List<User> createAndPersistRandomUsers(int count) {
  return IntStream.range(0, count)
    .boxed() // returns Stream<Integer>
    .map(UserBuilder::random) // returns Stream<User>
    .peek(userRepo::persist) // Collateral persist of user, returns Stream<User>
    .collect(toList()); // returns List<User>
}
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that this is not a `forEach` like action as the question asked for, as `peek` will just process items as they happen to be processed to accommodate the terminal operation. E.g. if the terminal operation is `findAny`, the only item you can be sure `peek` will see is the matching item, all others might get skipped. This may even change in an implementation dependent way, e.g. the current implementation processes all items when the terminal operation is `count`, future versions may skip the entire processing if the underlying `Spliterator` has the `SIZED` characteristic.

Comment: @Holger I agree, but for the use case in this question (in which the terminal operation processes all the elements of the Stream) I think it produces the expected behavior (i.e. each User returned in the list will also be persisted as a side effect. Of course there's no real advantage to doing it this way rather than first producing the list and then persisting all the Users).

Comment: Right, it works here that’s why I just said “worth noting” because I suspect that otherwise we will have a follow-up question on SO as soon as the OP changes the terminal operation.

Comment: Thanks! Your answers are very interesting :) The issue that @Holger points out is worth to investigate, though. I'm marking the question as answered